3rd part getting 403 permission denied error when accessing my api webhook
Using Laravel 7.0, I have API webhook setup so that a 3rdd party can push data to me. the webhook is not using authentication. All worked fine until a few days ago when they started getting

You don't have permission to access /api/sctest/inbound on this
server. Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered
while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

API uses groups and middleware validator
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'inbnd',
    'middleware' => ['xxxxxx.webhook'],
],function () {
    Route::post('inbound', 'myController@store');
});

I'm not sure why the authentication suddenly triggered. Any ideas how to use no-auth webhooks?
I tried removing the $this->registerPolicies() from AuthServiceProvider. I disabled the return route('login') from the app/Http/Middleware/Authericate and removed AuthorizesRequests from the main Controller.

somewhere in your code you are throwing a permission exception

It was a change on the server that I wasn't told about. They blocked certain user-agents or blank user-agent. They didn't bother to warn me about it though. Hours and hours of troubleshooting and hair-pulling!!
